# Extended draft mode which includes source information for manual print-out to source synchronisation

Tags: sectioning, floats, cross-referencing, citing, draft

I'm looking for a kind of extended draft mode which places the source code position of paragraphs, sectioning commands and figures etc. as marginpars or similar in the PDF, so that they appear on a print-out.

#### Background

I often give my paper drafts or (parts of) my thesis as PDFs to my coauthors/contributors and/or supervisors, respectively. They usually print it out and make corrections and remarks on paper. We tend to meet and I bring a Netbook (small Laptop) with me so that I can make the changes directly to the LaTeX code while we discus them.

The issue is that they make statements like "on the Xth line in the Yth paragraph on page *Z* it should be *foo* not *bar*" or "Figure *X* should be bigger".  Now I have trouble converting that to the location in the LaTeX source code. I think I could use SyncTeX and have the PDF open, then click on the position they mention to get to the source (I never used it so far), but this doesn't work in this case anyway because *normally I already made several changes on the source file since they printed the PDF out!* Editing should be quickly and easily possible, so I can't start handling two different versions of source code and PDFs etc. At the moment I simply search for parts of the original text they mention, but this doesn't work all the time because this text might not be fully verbatim like that in the source file due to line breaks etc.

#### Tasks:

I like to get the following:

- Beside every sectioning title and start of paragraph (i.e. about one number per paragraph) I like to have the source line number displayed (e.g. as `\marginpar`)
- There where the code of a source file starts (`\include`d chapters but also sections included using `\input`) I like to have the name of the source file printed.
- Figures should be marked with the name of the image files while the images are still displayed! If the figure is a diagrams (`tikzpicture` etc.) from an external file then the file name is also to be displayed. (Which actually might be already the case from the previous point).
- `\label`s and `\ref`s should be displayed using the internal name (as `\marginpar`s again)
- Bonus: Citiation keys (`\cite`) should be displayed like labels.

I know about packages which do display labels so this should be easily done but the rest needs some custom code I think.

Comment: Can LaTeX have access to the linenumbers of the file it's working from? If so, then that would be a start!

Comment: @Seamus: Yes, I think so. The warning messages etc. print it. There is also some related code in the `\begin` macro.

Comment: Another way to handle the problem might be to use version control and check out the version you gave to your collaborator as you meet and make changes to a branch of that version, then you merge the changes you made during the meet with the changes you made after sending the file to your collaborator. Of course, merging might result in conflicts that you have to resolve.

Comment: @N.N.: I'm using version control. This is as good idea.

Comment: @MartinScharrer I usually merge my dev branch to master everytime I'm ready to show the document to anyone. That way I can now what the latest submitted version is by looking for the latest merge into master. Also you can tag a commit (e.g. `git tag foo`) or write in the message commit that it's the version you submitted to be able to easily find them.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, to echo and extend N.N.'s advice, I'm using the `svninfo` package in my thesis, which tags each page with the filename and revision number of the actively-being-processed file as each page is shipped out.  (So if you have a short file `\include`d, that may not show up in the page tags.)

Comment: @MartinScharrer, could you get most of the effects you want (except the paragraph->line numbers) by doing `\g@addto@macro\ref{\marginpar{Ref: ##1}}` and its equivalents for `\cite` and `\label` etc?

Comment: @BenLerner: I do similar things but using `svn-multi` (which I wrote) instead of `svninfo`. It's better to use one of the existing packages to do the cites and labels.

Comment: @MartinScharrer, touche :)  I know the packages I use, but haven't linked them back to their authors in my head...  I suggested the add-to-macro solution above partly to clarify what effect you were after, and partly because if it truly is that short to implement, I tend not to include an extra package when I can do it myself that easily.  (And, if it doesn't exist, then it makes for a great and tiny package itself :-p)

Comment: @Seamus: The line number is given by the TeX primitive `\inputlineno` which is a number register. So `\the\inputlineno` would print it.

Comment: @Martin And since you only need the approximate number, you could add `\marginpar{\the\inputlineno}` to a paragraph hook...

Comment: @Martin So you want something like [what is suggested here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10513/215) but with `\the\inputlineno` instead of a counter...

Comment: @Martin: I think this question deserves the {draft} tag, so I had to remove another tag (and chose {printing}).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The basic functionality of adding input line numbers to the start of each paragraph can be achieved like so:

```
\usepackage[excludeor]{everyhook}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newif\ifnotmarginhook
\notmarginhooktrue
\PushPostHook{par}{%
  \ifnotmarginhook
  \notmarginhookfalse
  \marginnote{\small\ttfamily\the\inputlineno}
  \notmarginhooktrue
  \fi
}
```

Which I shamelessly stole from [TH's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10513/automatically-assign-a-number-to-every-paragraph/10576#10576) to a related question.
On that question, people were saying that hooking into the paragraph like this is not a great idea because lots of unexpected things are built with paragraphs. So use at your own risk.

I guess it would be neat to add a "only put a line number every *n* paragraphs" option: that wouldn't be too much work, just a little counter and `\ifnum` magic...

I've started work on a package that builds on this answer. The [github is here](https://github.com/scmbradley/draftinputlines). It has a `safemode` option that doesn't do any paragraph hooking trickery so it should be safer. Instead it just patches particular environments and sectioning commands directly. This should be more robust if the above breaks. `safemode` currently doesn't work with `titlesec` because it looks like `titlesec` doesn't use `\@startsection`. (Or something weirder is happening...)

Using Martin Scharrer's own `filehook` and `currfile` packages, you can signpost where inputted files start and finish like so:

```
\usepackage{filehook,marginnote}
\AtBeginOfInputs{%
  \@reversemargintrue
  \notmarginhookfalse
  \marginnote{\ttfamily\currfilename}
  \@reversemarginfalse
  \notmarginhooktrue
}

\AtEndOfInputs{%
  \@reversemargintrue%
  \notmarginhookfalse
  \marginnote{\ttfamily End \currfilename}%
  \@reversemarginfalse%
  \notmarginhooktrue
}
```

The `\@reversemargintrue` is just to make the notes appear on the opposite side (so that they don't overlap with line numbers). Same thing works for `\include` but you might want to handle that slightly differently just because of the forced pagebreaks. The package I'm working on allows you to put the current file name in the header and/or footer as well.

As mentioned in another answer, the [`showkeys`](http://dante.ctan.org/get/macros/latex/required/tools/showkeys.pdf) package can deal with the last two points.

Finally, adding the file name of included graphics. The following seems to work in my not very thorough testing. I don't know if this is at all the appropriate way to do it: I just searched `graphics.sty` for `draft` and bodged from there.

```
\usepackage{graphicx,marginnote,etoolbox}
\apptocmd\Gin@setfile{%
      \@reversemargintrue%
      \notmarginhookfalse%
      \marginnote{\ttfamily #3}%
      \@reversemarginfalse%
      \notmarginhooktrue%
}{}{}
```

I hope to have a version of the package on CTAN in a couple of weeks once I've done a little more testing, written some proper documentation and learned about `.dtx` files.

Comment: I tried testing this with `\Blinddocument` but of course, every linenumber is the same!

Comment: Damn. `\appto{\list}{\addlineno}` doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks. Adding the line number macro to the front of `\@startsection` which is used by all section and paragraph macros (but not chapters) should be enough.

Comment: Ooh. I've made it better. But I have to be careful how many times I edit this before it automagically becomes CW

Comment: @Martin `\preto{\@startsection}{\addlineno}` seems to break...

Comment: You need to use `\precmdto` (or so), because it has arguments. I tried now the `lineno` package and redefining the `\thelinenumber` macro to `\the\inputlineno`. It kind of works but shows the input line number of every *end* of every paragraph for each of its lines. It's a start.

Comment: The command is `\pretocmd`. `lineno` has an option to only put a number every `n` lines...

Comment: Floats are hard. But it's easy to patch `\caption`...

Comment: Accepting suggestions for what to call this if I turn it into a package. `extradraft`? `inputlines`?

Answer (score 3):

Do you know the [`showkeys`](http://dante.ctan.org/get/macros/latex/required/tools/showkeys.pdf) package, which provides solutions for your last two points?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showkeys}

\begin{document}
\section{section name}\label{sec1}
Some text \dots
\section{section name}
As seen in section~\ref{sec1} or in \cite{bib}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{bib} Some bib entry
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: showkeys example]

Comment: As stated, I know that such packages exists. I'm looking for something which gives me also the rest. This of course requires a combination of packages and extra code I think.

Comment: Does it do citation as well?

Comment: @Martin: The manual says it does … and sorry for overlooking that you said your’re knowing some packages …

Comment: @Martin: To mak sure that I was right about the cites I extended my example. And it works as expected - but I don’t know if it works together with `biblatex`.

Comment: `showkeys` does work with biblatex. I just checked. (I don't know _how well_ it works, but it doesn't break...)

Answer (score 2):

For your first point, I recently (as in this evening) wrote a very small package doing just that (with a little help from `marginnote` and `everyhook`). It's called `srcline` and is [available from Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/urdh/latexhax/src/204f176cc00b/srcline/). Unfortunately it doesn't typeset numbers inside floats or lists yet, as that seems to mess up the document layout quite a bit, but it may be a good starting point.

**Edit:** I just realized that this is extremely similar to the solution/package proposed by Seamus.

Comment: If you use `\marginnote` from the `marginnote` package, you should be able to get margin notes from inside floats. They won't float, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: If you tried the same thing I did with the `everyhook` package, it will probably break `\paragraph`s... Maybe we should collaborate on a package?

Comment: @Seamus: I am using `\marginnote`. The problem was that with margin notes inside floats the layout changed too much compared to when not using them, which I felt was kind of purpose-defeating as the use case is being able to refer to a source code line while proofing the document. Re collaboration, I'm not sure. This was mostly a quick hack for myself and I don't really intend to extend it too much as I won't have time to do so.