# Source code line numbers in PDF

Tags: pdf, line-numbering, code, collaboration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Extended draft mode which includes source information for manual print-out to source synchronisation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23063/extended-draft-mode-which-includes-source-information-for-manual-print-out-to-sou)

I am writing a document in LaTeX which I compile to PDF, which I often proofread in order to find mistakes in equations, tables, etc. When I find a mistake, I have to search the tex files for the text in order to find the position in the source, which is a nuisance. I know there are some "inverse search" solutions, but I'm not sure they are feasible since i prefer to use vim in a console window.

Ideally, I would like to use a package that prints out the line numbers of the tex source file in the margin of the PDF file -- unfortunately I haven't found any package that does this. Does anyone have any suggestions or other solutions?

Comment: Short answer: there is a package in production, but it's stalled right now. See linked question for github link.