# Hooking into the header/footer mechanism

Tags: header-footer, hooks, patching

I have a switch I'd like to turn off for the headers and footers but keep on for the main body text. What commands actually tell TeX to write the headers and footers after the body text has been set and how would I add a switch before and after these commands (with `etoolbox` or similar?).

What I'm looking for is something like `\AtBeginPrintHeader`. In analogy to `\AtBeginDocument`, or the hooks from `everyhook` which allow you to do something at the beginning of each paragraph, mathmode etc. I know there's `bophook` for doing stuff at the beginning of the page, but I need something that does something between the main body text being written and the headers and footers being written.

Patching `\ohead` with `\apptocmd` from `etoolbox` obviously doesn't work because it's not `\ohead` that is called when TeX tries to set a header. `\ohead` sets the relevant internal macros to be what they should so that the header you want is set. So I guess what I want to know is what actually happens when the header is being set: what command should I `\appto` in order to have something happen right before the header is set?

Is there such a mechanism? Is it compatible with `scrpage2` and `fancyhdr`?

Here's the example. I've used `everyhook` to add input line numbers to each paragraph. Awkwardly, this includes paragraphs in the header and footer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everyhook,marginnote}
\newif\ifnotmarginhook
\notmarginhooktrue
\PushPostHook{par}{%
  \ifnotmarginhook%
  \notmarginhookfalse%
  {\marginnote{\small\ttfamily\the\inputlineno}}%
  \notmarginhooktrue%
  \fi%
}
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\newcounter{firstline}
\newcommand\nolineno[1]{\notmarginhookfalse #1\notmarginhooktrue}
\ohead{Problem $\to$}
\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

So I want to turn `\notmarginhookfalse` for the headers, and then turning it back on before I set more body text... Using `\ohead{\notmarginhookfalse Text}` doesn't seem to work.

So is there either a way to hook into the headers or some internal switch so I could do something like `\ifheaders` and modify things that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the `everyhook` package with the `[excludeor]` option, your solution should work as you expect. (I don't understand the numbering system in your example, but that's not relevant to the solution.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[excludeor]{everyhook}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newif\ifnotmarginhook
\notmarginhooktrue
\PushPostHook{par}{%
  \ifnotmarginhook%
  \notmarginhookfalse%
  {\marginnote{\small\ttfamily\the\inputlineno}}%
  \notmarginhooktrue%
  \fi%
}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcounter{firstline}
\newcommand\nolineno[1]{\notmarginhookfalse #1\notmarginhooktrue}
\rhead{\nolineno{Problem $\to$}}
\begin{document}
Some text

Some text
\end{document}
```

[image: partial output of code]

Comment: Seamus may be referring to [this related comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25169/source-code-line-numbers-in-pdf) on linking your source code with your PDF output.

Comment: I'm actually referring to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23063/extended-draft-mode-which-includes-source-information-for-manual-print-out-to-sou) but yes.

Comment: I like this solution to my _actual_ problem, but I guess I'd still like a general solution to hooking into the header/footer mechanism.

Comment: But I think that the general solution is the same; the problem with your example was in how the `everyhook` package works, not with the possibility of setting conditional elements within the header and footer.