# Why does a negative after skip in \@startsection go weird if you fiddle with the everypar hook?

Tags: sectioning, boxes, sections-paragraphs

So, I'm trying to answer this question: [Extended draft mode which includes source information for manual print-out to source synchronisation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23063/extended-draft-mode-which-includes-source-information-for-manual-print-out-to-sou)
and I've run into a weird problem. Check out this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{everyhook,marginnote}
\newif\ifnotmarginhook
\notmarginhooktrue
\PushPreHook{par}{%
  \ifnotmarginhook
  \notmarginhookfalse
  \smash{\marginnote{\small\ttfamily\the\inputlineno}}
  \notmarginhooktrue
  \fi
}
\makeatletter
% \renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
%                                     {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
%                                     {1em}%
%                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\section{This works}

Here is some text and it will go on and on
Here is some text and it will go on and on
Here is some text and it will go on and on

\subsection{This too}

Here is some text and it will go on and on
Here is some text and it will go on and on
Here is some text and it will go on and on

\paragraph{Broken!}

Here is some text and it will go on and on
Here is some text and it will go on and on
Here is some text and it will go on and on

\end{document}
```

[image: broken!]

If you change the definition of `\paragraph` to have a positive value for afterskip (as in the commented out redefinition) then everything is fine. What is going on and how do I fix it? It looks like something is messing with boxes, but I don't understand what...

It looks like there's some funny business going on: my guess is that the negative skip means that TeX does `\rlap` of the paragraph name, measures the text of the paragraph title, then puts that much space at the start of a noindent paragraph plus the afterskip amount. Is something like that going on? How can I stop it overlapping?

Comment: The `\paragraph` command uses `\everypar` to typeset its title at the start of the next paragraph, so there's nothing really surprising that a conflict can exist. In your example, the problem seems to disappear by using `\PushPostHook` instead of `\PushPreHook` and recompiling twice.

Comment: Building upon Philippe Goutet's suggestion, I'd note that the `everyhook` documentation has a remark along the lines of "careful if you use `\PushPreHook{par}`: you should `\setbox0\lastbox` and put `\box0` after your tokens, to propagate the indentation box". Indeed, indentation removal (by `\@doendpe` and friends) is done with `\lastbox`.

Comment: @Bruno I did see that, but I couldn't quite get an example working. I think mainly because I don't understand enough about the box handling macros and how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\marginnote` command, when stripped down to what it does in your context, is more or less

```
\newcommand*{\marginnote}[1]{\setbox0\vbox{#1}\wd0=0pt\box0}
```

and `\paragraph` is

```
\renewcommand*{\paragraph}[1]{%
  \global\@noskipsectrue
  \everypar{%
    \if@noskipsec
      \global\@noskipsecfalse
      {\normalfont\textbf{#1}}\quad
    \else
      \everypar{}%
    \fi
  }%
}
```

The problem comes from the `\vbox` of `\marginnote` (if you change it to `\hbox`, the problem disappears in your context). What causes the word  `Broken!` to be typesetted over the text of the paragraph is just the change of width of the `\vbox` (in fact `\marginnote` also modifies its height and depth, which is why it is also moved up in  your example).

Here's the full stripped down code showing the phenomenon (the margin numbers are not correctly placed as `\marginnote` would have to do a few more things for that):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{everyhook}

\newif\ifnotmarginhook
\notmarginhooktrue
\PushPreHook{par}{%
  \ifnotmarginhook
    \notmarginhookfalse
    \marginnote{\small\ttfamily\the\inputlineno}%
    \notmarginhooktrue
  \fi
}

%\newcommand*{\marginnote}[1]{\setbox0\hbox{#1}\wd0=0pt\box0}% works
\newcommand*{\marginnote}[1]{\setbox0\vbox{#1}\wd0=0pt\box0}% doesn't work

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\paragraph}[1]{%
  \global\@noskipsectrue
  \everypar{%
    \if@noskipsec
      \global\@noskipsecfalse
      {\normalfont\textbf{#1}}\quad
    \else
      \everypar{}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{This works}

Here is some text and it will go on and on
Here is some text and it will go on and on
Here is some text and it will go on and on

\subsection{This too}

Here is some text and it will go on and on
Here is some text and it will go on and on
Here is some text and it will go on and on

\paragraph{Broken!}

Here is some text and it will go on and on
Here is some text and it will go on and on
Here is some text and it will go on and on

\end{document}
```

Of course, here your solution is to use `\PushPostHook` as already mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

(This doesn't answer the question *per se*, but does provide a workaround.)

Attaching the `\marginpar` command to the post-par hook instead (i.e. `\PushPostHook`) seems to magically fix the issue:
[image]

(The extra spaces seen at the beginning of the line are from spaces in the hook.)