# Reference line in document's own source code

Tags: sourcecode

I am commenting on a LaTeX document (with `todonotes`), and I would like to put a reference to a line in the source code, writing e.g.:

> See the code around line 123 of foo.tex to please fix this ugly equation.

`foo.tex` itself is included into a `main.tex` document, which contains the document's head and `\include` statements to all other document parts.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: You can just write `\todo{See the code at line 123 of foo.tex}`. But that isn't what you're asking, obviously. Could you be clearer what you want? You want to use the `\label` and `\ref` mechanism to refer to a line in the code?

Comment: I am using `\todo{foo}` to place a little comment on the side of my document. Often, these comments are about a misplaced character or a suggested fix of the underlying source. In these cases, I want the reader/author to be quickly able to locate the part I commented on in the source. Therefore I need the line number and source file where my comment is located in.

Comment: TeXworks allows to go from PDF output to the tex file.

Comment: Which would be feasible if I could force everyone who works with my code to use TeXworks. ;) Myself, I am not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the magic of `\inputlineno` and the `currfile` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{currfile}
\begin{document}
\section{Section}
\edef\myline{\the\inputlineno}
\todo{Fix code at line \myline\ of file \currfilename}

Lorem

\end{document}
```

I started working on a package that uses these tricks to help you keep track of where you are in the input file. It was inspired by [this question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23063/215)
 It's called [`draftinputlines`](https://github.com/scmbradley/draftinputlines). I am currently writing up my PhD. thesis, so development has slowed, somewhat.

Comment: Sweet! This is already one part of the solution. Is there now also a way to put the source file's name in there (e.g., if my PDF is compiled from a multi file .tex source)?

Comment: @mSSM see edit. You need a package to do it, but it should work…

Comment: Awesome; "watch"ing your progress on Github now. :)

Got to wait a couple of minutes before accepting your answer; you were too fast!

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: I need to `\edef` `\myline` every single time before using it? Isn't there a command that does not expand the argument before I actually call it?

Comment: @mSSM If the `todo` note is always near where you want the line number to point to, you could just put `\the\inputlineno` inside the todo note. Doing it this way, you can have the line number and the todo note to be far apart. It depends precisely what you want. I guess there's some clever tricks you could do to build a sort of `\label` / `\ref` system for line numbers, but I don't know whether it would be worth it.