# Safer alternative to everypar in creating a custom paragraph format in an environment?

Tags: formatting, page-breaking, paragraphs, widows-orphans

I'm trying to create an environment where each paragraph

- gets some stylized text prepended to it (e.g. "***Tips:*** ")
- is not allowed to be broken up across pages

Based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33925/2041), I've managed to achieve this using `everypar` and `windowpenalties`, but I'm wondering if there's a better way. I've [read](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/119760/2041) many times that `everypar` should be avoided if possible since many packages override it.

While my use of `everypar` is my main concern, I would also appreciate suggestions around `windowpenalties`. Is there a better approach?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{parskip}

\raggedbottom

\newenvironment{tips}
    {%
        \widowpenalties 1 10000%
        \everypar{{\fontshape{\itdefault}\fontseries{\bfdefault}\selectfont Tip:\enspace}}%
    }
    {}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{tips}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{tips}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not `\itshape\bfseries`? There is almost never a need to use `\selectfont` in LaTeX except in defining font commands, but here you just want standard out-of-the-box stuff: italic bold. Why the fuss?

Comment: @cfr Because I'm a beginner and I don't know any better. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see. If you are using those commands as a beginner, you should complain to your teacher! Or find a better source of information. (There's a question somewhere listing resources for beginners.) I teach beginners LaTeX and I definitely don't tell them to use `\selectfont`. (I can't remember if I show them this at all, but I certainly don't suggest they use it.)

Comment: I assumed if you were trying to do this that you knew what you were doing ;). (I've never used `\everypar` that I recall.  I don't remember ever using `\widowpenalties` either ....)

Comment: I'm reteaching myself after a decade hiatus, mainly through this website (although I have skimmed a few ctan manuals as well).

Comment: Could redefining `\par` within the environment work?

Comment: To prohibit page breaks bewtween *any* two lines of a paragraph, you must set `\interlinepenalty = 10000`, not `\widoowpenalties 1 = 10000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another, not perfect, option.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newenvironment{tips}
  {\def\par{\futurelet\tmptoken\dopar}%
   \def\dopar{\ifx\tmptoken\par\else\ifx\tmptoken\endgraf\else\ifx\tmptoken\end\else
       \endgraf\nobreak\textbf{\textit{Tip}:\enspace}\fi\fi\fi}%
   \interlinepenalty=10000 \par}
  {\endgraf}

\begin{document}

\begin{tips}
\kant*[1]

\kant*[2]

\kant*[3]
\end{tips}

\end{document}
```

However, I think this is much safer (and not less simple):

```
\newenvironment{tips}
  {\par
   \def\tip{\par\nobreak\textbf{\textit{Tip}:\enspace}}%
   \interlinepenalty=10000 }
  {\par}
```

and use

```
\begin{tips}

\tip whatever
\tip you
\tip want
\tip \kant[2]

\end{tips}
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel! In your second suggested approach, could you please explain what the extra `\par` commands do? I thought that having multiple `\par` in a row would insert a bunch of unwanted vertical space, and I was surprised to find that LaTeX collapses them.

Comment: `\par` ends a paragraph, if you already ended one, and there's nothing more, the next `\par` doesn't *end* another paragraph, so, in a way, as you say, TeX collapses them. The extra `\par`s are there to be safe, to ensure that the paragraph before `\begin{tips}` is properly ended, and to ensure that the paragraph ends after the last `\tip` (if not, the next lines of text might be taken as part of that same paragraph).

Comment: Got it. I'm going to go with your second approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

***I don't suggest using this. Stick to `\everypar`. It will be much safer.*** However, there is work in the pipeline which will make this easier in the future, thanks to the efforts of the LaTeX 3 developers.

Here's an example, just for the `\everypar` bit:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip,l3galley,xparse}
\raggedbottom
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \g_splicer_saved_tl
\NewDocumentEnvironment{tips}{}
{
  \group_begin:
  \tl_gset:NV \g_splicer_saved_tl \g_galley_par_begin_hook_tl
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_galley_par_begin_hook_tl
  {
    \textit{ \bfseries Tip: } \enspace
  }
}
{
  \tl_gset:NV \g_galley_par_begin_hook_tl \g_splicer_saved_tl
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\begin{tips}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{tips}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

[image: L3 tips]

Comment: Why not `\tl_gset_eq:NN` instead of `\tl_gset:NV`?