# Number and reference paragraphs

Tags: cross-referencing, margins, counters, paragraphs, legal-style

For "law-documents" you often want to enumerate every paragraph and cite them somewhere else in your document. This enumeration shall increase through the whole document and have the possibility to reference.

So I want to have something like that:

```
\p{mylabel} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...

Another without label \c{mylabel}.
```

Which shall be (with numbers in margin):

```
1  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...

2  Another without label (cf. mn. 1).
```

Doesn't matter if clickable in PDF or not so far.

Is there a package for that or some style?
Would be great!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our site. You want to number every paragraph or only every paragraph starting with `\p{somelabel}`?

Comment: Every paragraph. Would be great if it does this automagically. Without a \p at the beginning of every par.

Comment: I've found this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10513/27635

Answer (score 3):

What about simply using an empty `\paragraph` sectioning command?

```
\documentclass{article}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{}\label{mylabel} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\paragraph{} Another without label (cf. mn. \ref{mylabel}).
\end{document}
```

[image]

and, if you don't like the spacing, use the `\titlespacing` command from the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{1em}{1em}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{}\label{mylabel} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\paragraph{} Another without label (cf. mn. \ref{mylabel}).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Moreover, you can adjust the number with the command `\titleformat`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\renewcommand{\theparagraph}{\arabic{paragraph}}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{1em}{1em}
\titleformat{\paragraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{}\label{mylabel} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
\paragraph{} Another without label (cf. mn. \ref{mylabel}).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just great! But which commands do LaTeX for automatically have paragraphs? I would rather rewrite that and give the opportunity to disable such enumeration. So (%=newline due to no markup in comments -.-):

    foo%
%
    bar%
%
    \nop baz%

Instead of

    \p foo%
    \p bar%
    baz%

Comment: @MikePretzlaw When you want to disable numbering, simply add `\let\newpar\paragraph \renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\newpar*{#1}}` in the preamble.

Comment: +1 for simplicity :) On the other hand, this solves the easy part of the problem, the question how to do it automatically still remains open...

Comment: @tohecz Thanks. About automating the process, probably you better than me know a solution ;-)