# How to wrap a `\newcommand*` into a multi-paragraph environment?

Tags: macros, environments, paragraphs, starred-version

As stated [elsewhere](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1057/430), it is usually quite recommended to use the starred `\newcommand*` instead of `\newcommand` since this helps finding missing `}`s by disallowing paragraphs in its argument. Every now and then, it is however desired to let such a command, e.g. [`\pdfmarkupcomment`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment), act on (parts of) multiple paragraphs<sup>+</sup>. Is there any way to define an environment (say, `pdfmarkedup`, or can the environment share the command's name?) such that it automatically wraps each paragraph into the desired single-paragraph command? I.e.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\newenvironment{pdfmarkedup}{%
    % insert magic here
}

\begin{document}
\begin{pdfmarkedup}[markup=Highlight]{no comment}
I'm a little paragraph short and stout.
Here is my last stop.

Here is my successor.
When I get all wrapped up,
Hear me shout!

Just write me down
and pour me out.

I'm a clever environment, yes it's true.
Here's an example of what I can do.
I can wrap my paragraphs each into a command.
Just put me around them and pour me out.
\end{pdfmarkedup}

\end{document}
```

should be equivalent to

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}

\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{
I'm a little paragraph short and stout.
Here is my last stop.
}{No comment}

\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{
Here is my successor.
When I get all wrapped up,
Hear me shout!
}{No comment}

\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{
Just write me down
and pour me out.
}{No comment}

\pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight]{
I'm a clever environment, yes it's true.
Here's an example of what I can do.
I can wrap my paragraphs each into a command.
Just put me around them and pour me out.
}{No comment}

\end{document}
```

---

<sup>+</sup> In my example of `\pdfmarkupcomment`, it would be acceptable to have the same comment repeated over each paragraph.

Comment: yes sorry I just deleted that comment I misread the text, but still fixing the example so it loads all the right packages to run the example would be good

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The second form shouldn't need more than a `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{pdfcomment}\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` wrapped around it, the first form obviously needs the sought environment's definition in addition. Probably some iteration over the paragraphs inside...But `pdfmarkupcomment` is really just an example, this might as well be any other star-defined macro, e.g. `\newcommand*{\red}[#1]{{\color{red}#1}}`

Comment: Strongly related, maybe even duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10526/430

Comment: Don't add that to the comment _add it to the example_!! But as I said in my original comment, in general (as for the `\color` example) I can think of no cases where the complexity of doing this do not outweigh the benefits of the `*` form so simply using `\newcommand` would be preferable, But if you have and existing command that only works on text runs it could be done, probably although the details _would_ depend on the command

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the `environ` package?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, added. In how far would the details depend on the command? Probably on the number of (optional) arguments, but aside from that?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler So you want `\begin{pdfmarkedup}a\par b\par c\end{pdfmarkedup}` to be equivalent to `\pdfmarkupcomment{a}\par\pdfmarkupcomment{b}\par\pdfmarkupcomment{c}`?

Comment: @egreg Precisely, I should edit the question a bit I guess

Comment: you could grab the whole environment with environ as in egreg's answer then what you do next depends on the command. In some cases it would be enough to define `\par` as `\egroup\bgroup\foo` so the command stops and starts at each blank line., Other commands really need explicit `{}` so there you would have to scan over the text splitting at `\par` and adding `\foo{...}` which is more general but more complicated, but as egreg's shown that I'll leave him to get the tick:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the power of `expl3` together with `environ`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ,xparse}

\usepackage{pdfcomment}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{pdfmarkedup}[2][]
 {
  \kienzler_pdfmarkedup:Vnn \BODY { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_kienzler_pdfmarkedup_pars_seq
\cs_new_protected:Nn \kienzler_pdfmarkedup:nnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_kienzler_pdfmarkedup_pars_seq { \par } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_kienzler_pdfmarkedup_pars_seq
   {
    \tl_if_blank:nF { ##1 }
     {
      \pdfmarkupcomment[#2]{##1}{#3} \par
     }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \kienzler_pdfmarkedup:nnn { V }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}
\begin{pdfmarkedup}[markup=Highlight]{no comment}
I'm a little paragraph short and stout.
Here is my last stop.

Here is my successor.
When I get all wrapped up,
Hear me shout!

Just write me down
and pour me out.

I'm a clever environment, yes it's true.
Here's an example of what I can do.
I can wrap my paragraphs each into a command.
Just put me around them and pour me out.
\end{pdfmarkedup}

\end{document}
```

We absorb the environment's content with `environ`, then split it in a sequence at `\par` tokens. Each item of the sequence is passed to `\pdfmarkupcomment`.

Comment: I frankly don't have the faintest clue how this works (yet), but it does, so here's the checkmark. I guess this can be generalized into a `\createenvironmentfromcommand` somehow...

Comment: @TobiasKienzler The main obstacle is the syntax of the original command.