# How to combine numbered paragraphs, two columns, hanging indentation?

Tags: numbering, two-column, paragraphs, columns, hangindent

I have trouble combining several features. In an environment like "numberedpars" below, I would like to

- ... automatically number paragraphs exclusively on the left side in a two-sided book and reset the counter for each new environment. The numbers should be flushed right. Preferably, the numbers should be part of the text and not in the margin.
- ... have the text in two columns.
- ... have the first line of a paragraph not indented and the following lines hanging.

Is this even possible?

What I got so far: Automatically numbered paragraphs (even though it's not exclusively on the left side, the numbers are not flushed right, and the numbers are in the margin). Borrowed from the reply by T.H. here: [Automatically assign a number to every paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10513/automatically-assign-a-number-to-every-paragraph)

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///lualatex/[-synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode]

\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[excludeor]{everyhook}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{8pt}
\newcounter{parcount}
\newif\ifnumberedpars
\newenvironment{numberedpars}{%
    \PushPreHook{par}{%
        \ifnumberedpars
        \stepcounter{parcount}%
        \numberedparsfalse
        \marginpar{\arabic{parcount}}%
        \numberedparstrue
        \fi
    }%
    \numberedparstrue
}{%
    \PopPreHook{par}%
}

\reversemarginpar

\begin{document}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\section*{Section Headline}

\subsection*{Subsection Headline}

Some info

\subsubsection*{Subsubsection Headline 1}

\begin{numberedpars}
AA: This is a short paragaph.

BB: This is a rather long paragraph spanning more than one line if we extend this really really long.

AA: Again another rather long long paragraph spanning more than one line if we extend this really really long.

BB: And here we stop this conversation.
\end{numberedpars}

\subsubsection*{Subsubsection Headline 2}

\setcounter{parcount}{0}
\begin{numberedpars}
    AA: This is a short paragaph.
    
    BB: This is a rather long paragraph spanning more than one line if we extend this really really long.
    
    AA: Again another rather long long paragraph spanning more than one line if we extend this really really long.
    
    BB: And here we stop this conversation.
\end{numberedpars}

\subsubsection*{Subsubsection Headline 3}

\setcounter{parcount}{0}
\begin{numberedpars}
    AA: This is a short paragaph.
    
    BB: This is a rather long paragraph spanning more than one line if we extend this really really long.
    
    AA: Again another rather long long paragraph spanning more than one line if we extend this really really long.
    
    BB: And here we stop this conversation.
\end{numberedpars}


\subsubsection*{Subsubsection Headline 4}

\setcounter{parcount}{0}
\begin{numberedpars}
    AA: This is a short paragaph.
    
    BB: This is a rather long paragraph spanning more than one line if we extend this really really long.
    
    AA: Again another rather long long paragraph spanning more than one line if we extend this really really long.
    
    BB: And here we stop this conversation.
\end{numberedpars}

\subsubsection*{Subsubsection Headline 5}

\setcounter{parcount}{0}
\begin{numberedpars}
    AA: This is a short paragaph.
    
    BB: This is a rather long paragraph spanning more than one line if we extend this really really long.
    
    AA: Again another rather long long paragraph spanning more than one line if we extend this really really long.
    
    BB: And here we stop this conversation.
\end{numberedpars}

\end{document}
```

All my attempts to add more of the mentioned features has broken things for me. I greatly appreciate any working ideas.

**Edit:** Because it is rather difficult to explain, here is a screenshot of what I'm trying to do, created with LibreOffice Writer (though it's still missing the numbers being flushed right):

**Edit 2:** Ah sorry, the first screenshot was still missing the hanging indentation, it should look like this (even though not everything is perfectly aligned yet):

[image]

**Edit 3:** Celdor, your EDIT3 almost does it. It is still missing a genuine hanging indent. Let me explain. In case I use short initials (like "II") and long initials (like "WvW") spacing is not so nice anymore. There is either too much white space around "II" or not enough around "WvW" because the size of the initials label is fixed. It also becomes apparent that the initials are centered:

[image: Too much or not enough whitespace around the initials]

I think a genuine hanging indent needs the initials and the text to be connected. What I manage to do is have the initials flush left/justify (justification is what I'm looking for) by changing `c` to `l` in the line `\hspace{#3}\makebox[#4][l]{\textbf{#6:}}%` and raise the space after the initials (changing 1em to 2em in `\NewDocumentCommand{\numpar}{s O{0.5cm} O{2em} O{#2} O{#3} m}{%`). Now the paragraph numbers are flush right, and the initials are flush left and there is enough space for both "II" and "WvW":

[image: Paragraph numbers flush right, initials flush left and enough space]

Now justification is all good and there is some space between paragraph numbers and initials. Perfect. - But initials and text are still disconnected. What I'm looking for is this:

[image: Initials and text are connected, still a hanging indent with a certain size is used throughout.]

Initials and text are connected, still a hanging indent with a certain size is used throughout. To summarize: I don't want the space around the initials to be fixed, but initials and text to be connected and the size of the hanging indent to be fixed. I hope this clarifies what I'm missing.

Comment: I take it you want to allow page breaking inside and between paragraphs.  You could create a list environment, but each paragraph would have to start with \item.  (Lists allow multiple paragraphs per label.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast reply. Yes, I would like to allow page breaking inside and between paragraphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have got the description right, I'd propose using a mix of hangindent, hspace, and makebox

EDIT. Example with multi-columns. The solution is based on `tabular`.

EDIT2.
Added an option for a single column, which is executed by `*`; this can be broken between pages. The two columns solution has a flow from one column to the other as requested but can't be spread between pages. It seems each solution I came up with required usage of boxes. Perhaps it would require some internal coding which I am still learning, hence no solution on that particular feature, I am afraid.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image: aaa] | [image: aaa] |

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{geometry}

\newcounter{parcounter}
\newlength\hanglength

\NewDocumentCommand{\mypar}{s O{0pt} O{1cm} O{6pt} O{#3} O{#4} m m}{%
    % #1 - * for a single column
    % #2 - indentation before a number
    % #3 - width of a box containing a paragraph number
    % #4 - separation length after the number
    % #5 - width of a box containing a label
    % #6 - separation length after the label
    % #7 - label
    % #8 - the paragraph
    \setlength{\hanglength}{\dimexpr(#2 + #3 + #4 + #5 + #6)}
    \stepcounter{parcounter}
    \noindent
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
    {%
        \hspace{#2}\makebox[#3][r]{\arabic{parcounter}}%
        \hspace{#4}\makebox[#5][c]{#7}%
        \hspace{#6}%
        \hangindent=\hanglength\relax%
        #8\par
    }{%
        \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
                @{\hspace{#2}}
                >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#3}
                @{\hspace{#4}}
                >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#5}
                @{\hspace{#6}}
                p{\dimexpr(\textwidth-\hanglength)}
                @{}
            }
            \arabic{parcounter} &
            #7 &
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                \null\vspace{-\baselineskip}\begin{multicols}{2}#8\end{multicols}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{tabular*}\vspace{0.5\baselineskip}\par}}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{numberedpars}{+b}{%
    \setcounter{parcounter}{0}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}\par#1}{}


\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt

\section*{Section Headline}

\subsection*{Subsection Headline}

Some info

\begin{numberedpars}
    \mypar{AA}{\kant*[1][1-2]}
    \mypar{BB}{\kant*[2][1]}
    \mypar{AA}{\kant*[3][1]}
    \mypar{BB}{\kant*[4][1]}
    \mypar{AA}{\kant*[5][1]}
    \mypar{BB}{\kant*[6][1]}
    \mypar{CC}{\kant*[7][1]}
    \mypar{AA}{\kant*[8][1-3]}
    \mypar{BB}{\kant*[1][1-3]}
    \mypar{AA}{\kant*[2][1]}
    \mypar{BB}{\kant*[3][1]}
\end{numberedpars}

\subsection*{Subsection Headline}

\kant[2][1]

\begin{numberedpars}
    \mypar*{CC}{\kant*[1][1-3]}
    \mypar*{DD}{\kant*[2][1-3]}
    \mypar{CC}{\kant*[3][1-3]}
    \mypar{DD}{\kant*[4][1-3]}
    \mypar*{CC}{\kant*[5][1-2]}
    \mypar*{DD}{\kant*[6][1-2]}
\end{numberedpars}

\end{document}
```

---

EDIT3

A solution with the two-column sections.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image: aaa] | [image: aaa] |

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\newcounter{parcounter}

\NewDocumentCommand{\numpar}{s O{0.5cm} O{1em} O{#2} O{#3} m}{%
    % #1 - star - suppresses annotations
    % #2 - width of a box containing a paragraph number
    % #3 - separation length after the number
    % #4 - width of a box containing a label
    % #5 - separation length after the label
    % #6 - label
    %
    % \dimen0 contains width of a numbers and labels
    \setlength{\dimen0}{\dimexpr(#2 + #3 + #4 + #5)}
    \noindent
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\hspace{\dimen0}}{%
        \stepcounter{parcounter}%
        \makebox[#2][r]{\arabic{parcounter}}%
        \hspace{#3}\makebox[#4][c]{\textbf{#6:}}%
        \hspace{#5}}%
    \hangindent=\dimen0}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{numberedpars}{O{0.25pt} +b}{%
    \setcounter{parcounter}{0}
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{#1}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
        #2%
    \end{multicols}}{}

\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt

\section*{Section Headline}

\subsection*{Subsection Headline}

Some info

\begin{numberedpars}
    \numpar{AA} \kant*[1][1-2]
    
    \numpar{BB} \kant*[2][1-2]
    
    \numpar{AA} \kant*[3][1-2]
    
    \numpar{BB} \kant*[4][1-2]
    
    \numpar{AA} \kant*[5][1-2]
    
    \numpar{BB} \kant*[6][1-2]
    
    \numpar{AA} \kant*[7][1-2]
    
    \numpar{BB} \kant*[8][1-2]
    
    \numpar*{AA} \kant*[9][1-2]
    
    \numpar*{BB} \kant*[10][1-2]
    
    \numpar{BB} \kant*[3][1-3]
\end{numberedpars}

\section*{Another Section Headline}

\subsection*{Another Subsection Headline}

Even more info

\begin{numberedpars}[2pt]
    \numpar{CC}\kant*[1][1-3]
    
    \numpar*{}\kant*[2][1]
    
    \numpar{DD} \kant*[2][1-3]
    
    \numpar{CC} \kant*[3][1-3]
    
    \numpar{DD} \kant*[4][1-3]
    
    \numpar{CC} \kant*[5][1-2]
    
    \numpar{DD} \kant*[6][1-2]
\end{numberedpars}

\end{document}
```

---

---

EDIT4
Initials are no longer tabulated.

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Page 1 of EDIT 4] | [image: Page 2 of EDIT 4] |

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\makeatletter
    \newcounter{p@rc@unter}
    \NewDocumentCommand{\numpar}{s O{0.5cm} O{6pt} O{1cm} m}{%
        % #2 - width of a box containing a paragraph number
        % #3 - space between the number and initials
        % #4 - space of a hanging indentation
        % #5 - initials
        \hangindent=#4
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\hspace{#4}}{
            \stepcounter{p@rc@unter}
            \settowidth{\dimen0}{\arabic{p@rc@unter}}
            \setlength{\dimen1}{#2}
            \ifdim\dimen0<\dimen1
                \setlength{\dimen0}{\dimen1}
            \fi
            \makebox[\dimen0][r]{\arabic{p@rc@unter}}\hspace{#3}%
            \notblank{#5}{\textbf{#5:}}{}}}
    \NewDocumentEnvironment{numberedpars}{s O{0.4pt} O{14pt} +b}{%
        % #1 - * - if present, keep counting paragraphs without cancelling
        % #2 - column rule width
        % #3 - space between columns
        \IfBooleanF{#1}{\setcounter{p@rc@unter}{0}}
        \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
        \setlength{\columnseprule}{#2}
        \setlength{\columnsep}{#3}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            #4\par
        \end{multicols}}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
% \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\section*{Section Headline}
\subsection*{Subsection Headline}
Some info

\begin{numberedpars}
    \numpar{AA}
    \kant[1][1]

    \numpar{BB}
    \kant*[2][1-3]

    \numpar{II} \kant*[4][1-2]

    \numpar{WwW} \kant*[5][1]

    \numpar{D} \kant*[6][1]

    \numpar{EEE} \kant*[7][1-2]

    \numpar{II} \kant*[4][1-2]

    \numpar{WwW} \kant*[5][1]

    \numpar{D} \kant*[6][1]

    \numpar{EEE} \kant*[7][1-2]
\end{numberedpars}

\kant[10][1-3]


\section*{Section Headline}
\subsection*{Subsection Headline}
Some other info

\begin{numberedpars}
    \numpar{CDT}
    \kant*[8][1-2]

    \numpar{JPJ}
    \kant*[9][1-2]
\end{numberedpars}

Something

\begin{numberedpars}*
    \numpar{XYZABCD} \kant*[10][1-2]

    \numpar{II} \kant*[11][1-2]

    \numpar{WvW} \kant*[12][1-2]

    \numpar{D} \kant*[13][1-2]
\end{numberedpars}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solves problem (1) mentioned below. Let's set priorities and say having the numbers flushed right would be nice but is rather optional. By (2) I really mean a classical two column text layout. That's because I have many short lines and a long long text and would really like to save some space.

Comment: Does the new screenshot show anything closer to what you expected?

Comment: A little closer yes, but I think of something different. I added a screenshot of the expected result in my question post, please have a look.

Comment: See the EDIT3 in my answer. The vertical rule is set to `0.25pt` with an option to  change on demand; see the second page. Remarks: there is a starred version of `\numpar` in case multiple paragraphs are needed. It simply hides annotations and such paragraphs are not counted.

Comment: This looks pretty good, though there is one issue remaining: Having the label in a separate box with a fixed size is a problem. E.g., replace "AA" with "II" and "BB" with "WvW", simulating a short and a long label. No matter which size you use, the box is either too short for "WvW" or too long for "II". I think it would be better to have label and text in one box and use some `\hangindent` command. Is this possible?

Comment: Is the label in a separate box? - Well, somehow label and text are separated, that's what's problematic. (... Oh, I see, it's the label OF the box. I think we need the initials inside the box.) Maybe a combination of what you and John Kormylo did is possible.

Comment: I am sorry but it's still not clear what you want to achieve. I am afraid I run out of ideas. Every fine tuning details or a change you request takes time due to figuring out a solution and then testing. Perhaps if you provide the **EXACT** explanation including a screenshot that demonstrates **EXACTLY** what you want to achieve will help here. I am happy to help but it seems I kind of miss the main point any time I provide a solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help so far! I'm sorry, for not being more clear. I try to make it more clear now with several pictures. Please have a look at my question post once more.

Comment: Np. and thanks for the pictures. I have edited the answer and I believe the solution matches your description.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Perfect, EDIT4 is just what I was looking for. I'm accepting this answer. Though I also found a way to make the MWE in the other answer work, see my comment below. I may consider using that because I won't need to separate initials and text when inputing it. Your answer offers more settings (e.g. starred version for multiple paragraphs).

Comment: Thanks. I see the point of the other answer. @JohnKormylo managed to utilise a trick with `\def` meaning after control sequence LaTeX is consuming all tokens for an argument until non-char is encountered, there ":"; very clever :) I didn't think about it. You could try to add `\def\@numpar#1:{\numpar{#1}}\AtBeginEnvironment{numberedpars}{\everypar{\@numpar}}` at the end of group `\makeatletter...\makeatother` just before the line with`\makeatother` and see if John's approach can work here.